# Need help identifying invasive grass/weed in my landscaping + St Augustine grass (9A)

Tags: weed-control, weeds

I'm having an issue (among others) with my St Augustine lawn and flowerbed. I'm in zone 9A and this is happening in the sunniest part of the lawn, most gets sun from 8-9 am to 4-5 pm.  I'm about ready to call someone to come in and help get this under control but wanted your opinions first to see if this is something I can take care of on my own. I'm fairly certain this came in when I brought some dirt in to level my yard in a few spots. Any help identifying this would be greatly appreciated.

I'm fairly certain we're going to pull all the mulch and plants up, put down landscaping fabric then remulch.

See link below image for more photos:

[image: weed in flowerbed]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqeCC.jpg

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From what I've been hearing it's torpedo grass.... lovely!

Comment: Please please please do not put landscape fabric down!  This is the worst thing us humans can do for our landscape.  It does not stop weeds.  It does stop the life in your soil...because life needs decomposed organic matter and that dang fabric stops organic matter decomposed, to be available to the soil life.  It does nothing for weeds absolutely nothing. There are better ways to deal with weeds.  Weeds are like the last thing on my list for maintenance of landscapes. I know how easy they are to control...We need more information a few more pictures to be able to help!

Answer (score 1):

the bigger grass is seed from an areca palm is what it looks like to me.

Answer (score -1):

That looks just like a ground orchid I have. My leave are a little larger and look healthier , but mine get fertilizer , water and are in mostly shade  ( zone 8). Mine bloom in early spring ; Feb and Mar.